# mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm working on code for a poll. The admin can create questions and delete them. The user can choose answers from a dropdown menu to answer the questions. This dropdown menu is filled dynamically with a query request.

Now I want the user's name to be inserted in the database when he completes a poll, so he can't do that poll twice. That's what the code here is for.
This is the query I'm using:

```
$idfind = "SELECT `id` FROM `Umfragenteilnahme` WHERE `Username` ='$user'";
$id = mysql_query($idfind) or die (mysql_error());
if($id) {
    while($rpw = mysql_fetch_assoc($id)) {
        $id = $rpw['id']; // Using $rpw->id doesnt work
        echo $id; // it gives the right answer and everything works fine
                  //id= 4 for example
    }  
}
else {
    echo "Fehler"; // it does not report a fail
}
```

I know I should use the new `mysqli_...` tags. The code works absolutely fine and the query gives the right answer and works in MySql database as well.

But every time it gives this error

> mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in

or for the `(mysql_error())` this one:

> mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in.

Everything works fine, but it shows these errors. Why are these errors happening? How can I avoid them?

Edit:
Now i placed this in the beginning of the code after the first `<?php` :

```
set_error_handler ( function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
if (false!==stripos($errstr, 'mysql')) {
    $file = file($errfile);
    $code = '';
    for($i=max(0, $errline-8); $i<min($errline+8, count($file)); $i++) {
        $code .= sprintf('%4d | %s', $i+1, $file[$i]);
    }
    printf('<fieldset><legend>%s (%d), %s@%d</legend>
        <pre>%s</pre></fieldset>',
        htmlspecialchars($errstr), $errno,
        htmlspecialchars($errfile), $errline,
        htmlspecialchars( $code )
    );
}
else {
    return false;
}});
```

The output is this :

```
Benutzer id: 4
mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given (2), /censored/censored/www/Website2.0/btn_lehrer.php@36

29 | /* The $user is defined at start of code */
30 | /* With the next query i get the user-id from this specific user */
31 | 
32 | $idfind = "SELECT `id` FROM `Umfragenteilnahme` WHERE `Username`    =   '$user'";
33 | $id = mysql_query($idfind)or die (mysql_error());
34 |        if($id){
35 |            
36 |                    while($rpw = mysql_fetch_assoc($id)){
37 |                          $id = $rpw['id'];
38 |                           echo "Benutzer id: $id ";    //fehler       (Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be   resource, string given line 15)                                    
39 |                        }  
40 |                      
41 |                }
42 |                else{
43 |                     echo "Fehler bei der Bestimmung der Benutzer id!";
44 |                    }
```

I hope that you dont mind that it took so long but as i said i completely restructured my code.
Thanks for all the help so far maybe now someone has the answer to my problem. :)

Comment: Don't pass the query string to [mysql_error()](http://docs.php.net/mysql_error). You could/should pass the connection resource, i.e. the return value of mysql_connect.

Comment: I left the `echo(mysql_error());` now. But when i execute the code it is still saying that something is wrong. But how can something be wrong if the code delivers the right answer//id? This is the error now `Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in`. Thank you for your quick answers.

Comment: Is the only occurence of `mysql_fetch_assoc` in the code snippet you've posted?

Comment: Well, the actuall code is about 300 lines long  with html formular and that is just a small snippet out of the code. There are other `mysql_fetch_assoc()` commands into it. But the rest of the code works fine exept that i didnt used `mysqli_fetch..` commands there are no warnings or things that dont work at all. Based on this function there are no other `mysql_fetch_assoc`s.

Comment: The warning message contains the file name and line number. Does it point to _exactly_ the code you've posted?

Comment: Yes , esactly that line. Its the line where the while loop with the `mysql_fetch_assoc` starts.

Comment: And the code is still _exactly_ as you have posted it in your question? `$id=mysql_query(...` and no assignment to $id before fetch_assoc -> $id is not a string <- `expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in` <- not likely.

Comment: by the way this piece of code will not provide you the insert id `$id`. You should use `mysql_insert_id` which is explained in this page: http://php.net/manual/tr/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: Yeah but i do not insert or update something before, does `mysql_insert_id` also works in that case? thanks by the way for your help guys.

Comment: @VolkerK , yes its exactly the same piece of code , i just copyed and pasted it. I just dont understand this error because the code works absolutly fine. Exept this error. :( Thank you VolkerK for your help i really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning a string to $id within the loop, `$id = $rpw['id'];`. The next time mysql_fetch_assoc($id) is executed, $id is a string, hence the warning message.

```
while($rpw = mysql_fetch_assoc($id)) {
    echo "Benutzer id: ", $rpw['id'], "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: You are awesome!! Now theres no error message anymore! Thank you so much. But for the next steps of the code i need the result of the query in a variable. How can i do that now?

Comment: a) $rpw _is_ a variable, so the value is already "in" one. b) Choose another name for the variable. c) And in case you want to send another sql query based on that variable have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Comment: Is it possible to put a variable in there like that: `$raw['$fragenid2']`?

Comment: Yes, but without the single quotes, `$raw[$fragenid2]`, see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is actually your error message. You gave the function `mysq_error` your SQL query which is a string. The function takes a resource as a parameter as explained [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php). The resource should be the one that the function `mysql_connect` returns.

Also if you don't give any parameters to `mysql_error` it will use the last opened link as described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php). Removing the parameter `$idfind` will most likely solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer yet:
Could you please place

```
set_error_handler ( function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    if (false!==stripos($errstr, 'mysql')) {
        $file = file($errfile);
        $code = '';
        for($i=max(0, $errline-8); $i<min($errline+8, count($file)); $i++) {
            $code .= sprintf('%4d | %s', $i+1, $file[$i]);
        }
        printf('<fieldset><legend>%s (%d), %s@%d</legend>
            <pre>%s</pre></fieldset>',
            htmlspecialchars($errstr), $errno,
            htmlspecialchars($errfile), $errline,
            htmlspecialchars( $code )
        );
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

somewhere it gets executed before any of the mysql_* functions - at the top of the main script right after the first `<?php` would be fine - and then [add the output to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34386448/edit)?
The error handler is supposed to print the "surrounding code" for all mysql related warnings/errors and the (raw) output should look like

```
<fieldset><legend>mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given (2), ...test.php@21</legend>
            <pre>  14 |         );
  15 |  }
  16 |  else {
  17 |      return false;
  18 |  }
  19 | });
  20 | 
  21 | mysql_fetch_assoc('foo');
  22 | 
</pre></fieldset>
```

Comment: I try to do that as soon as possible. I dont have much time at the moment.But thanks for your help!!

Comment: Okay, i tried to do that now and i think its better to work on my complete code first until i can ask another question. I think otherwise i am just gonna waste your time. THANKS for your help and sry for not responding as fast as you did.

Comment: @ VolkerK I placed your code now and posted the output. I hope you can help me now.